# Rails: Class as Hash value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there any issues (performance or otherwise) to using a class as a hash value e.g.

```
  ERRORS = {
    'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' => Errors::RecordNotFound,
    'ActiveModel::RecordInvalid' => Errors::InvalidRecord
  }
```

And then to create an instance I would do:

```
ERRORS['ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'].new
```

of course the parameter passed to ERRORS would be a variable instead of a string, but I am doing this just as a demonstration.

What I see many doing is creating the hash as string values and then using `constantize` to instantiate the class:

```
  ERRORS = {
    'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' => 'Errors::RecordNotFound',
    'ActiveModel::RecordInvalid' => 'Errors::InvalidRecord'
  }
```

Then to instantiate:

```
ERRORS['ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound'].constantize.new
```

Does one have any advantages over the other?

Comment: The `constantize` option is slower, and also never do it with user-defined strings unless you have whitelisted certain class names

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't need to serialize this hash (e.g. to save it to database, send it over network or put as an argument of a sidekiq job), it should be OK. I would also opt for for the class values, not the string values with constantize.